# I have a list of user-inputted coordinates, how do i calculate the point that is as close as possible to all the coordinates?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, coordinates

I've used the code below to calculate the centroid before, but when there's a lot of points close to each other the centroid gets pulled to that direction making the distance from the coordinates to the calculated point less equal. How can I calculate a coordinate that has the least distance to a midpoint for all the coordinates?

```
$.each( routeStart, function(i, routeCoords){
      centroidx += parseFloat(routeCoords[0]);
      centroidy += parseFloat(routeCoords[1]);
    });
    endpoint = ol.proj.fromLonLat([(centroidx / routeStart.length), (centroidy / routeStart.length)])
```

Comment: [Centroid for multiple points](https://www.mathwords.com/c/centroid_formula.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finding the average of the points given. Instead, I think what you are looking for is the average of all the absolute maximums & minimums.

For example:

```
var points = [
    { x: 6, y: 1},
    { x: 3, y: 4},
    { x: 7, y: 8},
    { x: -4, y:-10},
    { x: -5, y:-11},
    { x: -5, y:-10}
  ]; 
var maxX, minX, maxY, minY;
points.forEach(point => {
    if(maxX === undefined || maxX < point.x) {
        maxX = point.x
    }
    if(minX === undefined || minX > point.x) {
        minX = point.x
    }
    if(maxY === undefined || maxY < point.y) {
        maxY = point.y
    }
    if(minY === undefined || minY > point.y) {
        minY = point.y
    }
});
var centerPoint = { 
    x: ((maxX + minX) / 2),
    y: ((maxY + minY) / 2)
};
console.log("Center point: ", centerPoint);
```

To test this, you can run the code above then add the following to the list of points. This should not change the center point.

```
{ x: -5, y:-10},
{ x: -5, y:-10},
{ x: -5, y:-10},
```